# Can I use `::class` notation in model functions - Laravel

Tags: php, class, laravel, laravel-5

I am cleaning code in my app. Seems I have a misconception about `::class` notation.

While in my `config/app.php` providers declared can be converted from say this: `'igaster\laravelTheme\themeServiceProvider',` into this
 `igaster\laravelTheme\themeServiceProvider::class,`, I cannot do the same for objects in models.

For instance, I have

```
public function relateds()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Related', 'item_id')->Where('itemkind', '=', 'capacitytypes', 'and')->Where('status', '!=', '2');
}
```

after the conversion into

```
public function relateds()
{
    return $this->hasMany(App\Models\Related::class, 'item_id')->where('itemkind', '=', 'capacitytypes')->where('status', '!=', '2');
}
```

I receive error

`FatalThrowableError in Model.php line 918:
Class 'App\Models\App\Models\Action' not found`

Does it mean that I cannot use the notation in models, or I do sth wrong?

Comment: I think this should work. The issue could be that you are referencing the related model within the namespace in a way that makes the full namespce come out in a way you don't want. Did you notice the path issue with `App\Models\App\Models\Action`? Try `Related::class` instead.

Comment: Try \App\Models\Related::class instead (additional backslash in the beginning)

Comment: Manuel, it worked. Much to my surprise, as I tried to do that myself. I must have miessed positive feedback from the app. Thank you. Please upgrade your comment into an answer.

Comment: But the thing is that you shouldn't *need* to do this.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I know  Laravel doesn't like me.

Answer (score 3):

Namespaces behave somewhat like file paths in this context in that when you reference one throughout your code, you can reference them relatively (In relation to current namespace) or absolutely (Full namespace).

When you're in a file that's namespaced like this one, if you omit the leading `\` character then you're referencing relatively. That's why it's looking for `App\Models\App\Models\Action`.

The file `config/app.php` is not namespaced and therefore any namespaces you provide are assumed to be relative to the root namespace, so you don't need a leading `\` character.

For reference though, there are a few things you could have done to fix your problem here.

- Firstly, as suggested in the comments you can put a `\` on the beginning so it becomes:

  ```
  public function relateds()
  {
      return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Related::class, 'item_id')->where('itemkind', '=', 'capacitytypes')->where('status', '!=', '2');
  }
  ```
- Secondly, you could `use` the class at the top of your file, just after the namespace declaration and then omit the full namespace when defining your relationship, like this:

  ```
  <?php

  namespace App\Models;

  use App\Models\Related;

  class Action extends Model
  {
      // ...

      public function relateds()
      {
          return $this->hasMany(Related::class, 'item_id')->where('itemkind', '=', 'capacitytypes')->where('status', '!=', '2');
      }
  ```
- Lastly and more simply, since your `Related` and `Action` models are both in the same `App\Models` namespace, you can omit the namespace entirely when defining your relationship, without having to `use` it at the top. So you would end up with this:

  ```
  public function relateds()
  {
      return $this->hasMany(Related::class, 'item_id')->where('itemkind', '=', 'capacitytypes')->where('status', '!=', '2');
  }
  ```